# cant update state even after copying it to a variable

Tags: reactjs, state

i have parent component SalesViewMain which has a useEffect function to call an async thunk redux function and sets these data to a useState.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getSalesAction(props.id)).unwrap().then(data=>{
        setSalesId(data.salesData.salesData[0].sales_id)
        setPayment(data.salesData.salesData[0].payment_type)
        setCashier(data.salesData.salesData[0].name)
        setDays(data.salesData.salesData[0].days)
        setDate(data.salesData.salesData[0].date)
        setProducts(data.salesData.products)
      })

},[])
```

then in that component i have a child component SalesViewProducts where i send the products data to the child component

```
<SalesViewProducts
        products={products}
        setProduct={setProducts}
        >
        </SalesViewProducts>
```

now in that child component im trying to call a function that will change the value of products state. ive done my research of copying the state first like [...props.products]. but even after copying it im unable to change the contents, met with the error cannot assign to read only property, why? ive already made a copy and i have no idea why this isnt working

```
const addProduct=(data)=>{

    var index;
    let copyArray = [...props.products]
    copyArray[0].quantity = 9
}
```

what should i do please help

Comment: `copyArray` is not a deep copy. `copyArray[0]` still points to `props.products[0]`.

Comment: what should i have done to perform a deep copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the object you want to update:

```
const addProduct=(data)=>{

    var index;
    let copyArray = [...props.products]
    copyArray[0] = {
        ...copyArray[0],
        quantity: 9
    }

    props.setProduct(copyArray)
}
```